# form textarea value invisible

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and in my title value attribute, I have the value from the database clearly displayed in the form on screen. However, the body value attribute is not appearing. Looking in the inspector, I can see the value has all the information from the database but it is not appearing on the screen. I am unclear why one is showing and the other is not. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code plus screenshot. Thank you in advance.

Edit view:

```
  <?php echo form_open('posts/update'); ?>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Add Title" value="<?php echo $post['title']; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Body</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Add Body" value="<?php echo $post['body']; ?>"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Post Controller Edit function:

```
        public function edit($slug) {
        $data['post'] = $this->post_model->get_posts($slug);
        if (empty($data['post'])) {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = 'Edit Post';

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    public function update() {
        $this->post_model->update_post();
        redirect('posts');
    }
```

The View

```
<?php echo form_open('posts/edit/' . $post['slug']); ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-secondary float-left mr-2">
</form>

<?php echo form_open('/posts/delete/' . $post['id']); ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: `<textarea>` elements don't have a `value` attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: `<textarea class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Add Body"><?php echo $post['body']; ?></textarea>`

Comment: Thank you miken32 and Vickel. I did not know that the textarea did not receive a value attribute. That solved my problem. Thank you sooooo very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello text area is define in outside of the you textarea input value like that.. and text value define in the value section of our input type text and vaue..**

```
   <textarea class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Add Body"><?php echo $post['body']; ?></textarea>
```

**other code will write like .. i hope you are well understanding textarea and text input**

```
 <input type="text" value="<?php echo $post['body']; ?>" class="btn btn-secondary float-left mr-2">
```

Comment: if you get your answer and its helpful for you so please give upvote so other people refer this answer  thank you !.